# My general questions for Citrus Engine

Tags: actionscript-3

I`m new to citrus engine and I found this engine just today. I am making my first flash game and I am thinking of this engine as my option. I just want to ask some general questions.

Sorry for asking without exploring yet, but can I make a custom skills for my hero? Like pressing 1 for slash, 2 for triple slash, and 3 for pressure bomb skill.

Can I make a custom class in CE for my boss, enemies, bullets, etc?

If I want to upload my game to Newgrounds(which requires only one SWF). Can Citrus Engine produce a single SWF file that wraps everything on my game? I doubted about this since CE has to have a swf for a hero, ground, etc. Please let me know about this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for all your questions.

[See this video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSwWCwLPw04&feature=fvwrel)

This is a brazillian game which have begun it's development using CE. What you're seeing was made with it, but seems that the project today have in use another frameowrk.

Comment: wow...its really good...i really like the graphics and the gameplay....but are you this is compiled on a single swf? I need the answer because its very crucial to me.. if I want to upload it in newgrounds....

Comment: I'm not sure if you can make a game with only one file using CE normally, but I heard is possible to do that making some arrangements in the framework.